# How to configure the DNS server java should use in jdk 9, 10 and 11

Tags: java, dns, java-9, java-11

For testing we have a DNS server that will respond with dummy records. Previously we could make java use our DNS server (here it is just using local host) by using:

```
"-Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers=127.0.0.1",
"-Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1=dns,sun",
```

This no longer works under jdk11. 
Is it possible to specify the DNS server to use under jdk11? If so how?

Edit:
I also attempted:

```
-Djava.naming.provider.url=dns://127.0.0.1
```

from https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/jdk.naming.dns/share/classes/com/sun/jndi/dns/DnsContextFactory.java but that did not work either.

Comment: That "feature" was removed in JDK 9, here's the release note on the issue: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-removed-features-3745614.html#JDK-8134577

Comment: To handle it, I would rather encourage you to setup the DNS server at the machine level instead of updating it in java.

Comment: @AlanBateman so it is impossible, would you please put that in as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

Defining an alternative DNS server is already not supported: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8134577

For testing you should use an alternative hosts file that could be defined by the `-Djdk.net.hosts.file=path_to_alternative_hosts_file` JVM option.

For example if you have a file with following content at `D:\test\hosts`

```
10.20.30.40        google.com www.google.com
```

Running this code with `-Djdk.net.hosts.file=D://test/hosts`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
        System.out.println(address);
    }
```

will print:

```
google.com/10.20.30.40
```